# How do I connect to MySQL 5.1 in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010

Does any one know how to connect to [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) 5.1 with [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010)?

I have already tried the [MySQL Connector/ODBC](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.1.html) route and it got me really nasty results. The table rows were all listed as a view in the views section and nothing at all was listed in the tables or procedures folder.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To get the Entity Frame working with VS2010, I had to do the following:

1. This only worked with Mysql .net Connector v6.3.1 (alpha).  Previous versions ignored VS 2010 (click Development Releases)
2. I had to rename my Framework\v1.1.4322\CONFIG folder.  Otherwise the install will fail.  Rename it back when finished

(I've blogged about this [here](http://christianpayne.com.au/2010/05/07/vs-2010-mysql-entity-framework-and-setup-wizard-ended-prematurely-because-of-an-error/))

**Update**
[6.3.2 is in beta](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=389424) and I can confirm this works.  (I didn't need to rename the framework folder)

Comment: +1: This worked for me. The other approach about deleting empty config dirs didn't work for me.

Comment: I can only see 6.3.2 beta on the site now, and it will not install with the CONFIG directory renamed.  I also tried renaming the v2 CONFIG dir, but Windows wouldn't let me do it.  Still looking for a MySQL connector for VS2010 that works (and is free).

Comment: Correct URL for the 6.3 beta version http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.3.html

(6.3.2 appears to be the current version)

Answer (score 14):

### **this seems to solve the issue**

UPDATED LINK TO LATEST RELEASE THANKS @Christian Payne

**Update**: looks like there is already a non-beta!!!!

http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: I had problems installing the alpha. You must get rid of empty Config folders for your .NET framework installations before running the MySQL installer, as described here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,354259,363768#msg-363768

Go to your Framework Folder: 

For x64 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\ 

For x86 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ 

For each folder inside there check if existis a folder with the name "Config" 

Then if the folder 'Config' is empty DELETE THIS FOLDER; 

After checking all folders Re-run the Installer.

Comment: This helped as well:  http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,354259,358381#msg-358381

Comment: This updated link is to the source code, not the installer.  You will need to compile this first or download the msi - http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=389424

Answer (score 4):

As someone else suggests..

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=382641

..fixes the problem.

I had v6.2.3 installed after I had vs2010 installed and the MySQL driver was not shown in the list of the Database Connect dialog. I wrongly assumed I should use the .NET ODBC drivers instead and it caused all sorts of problems. Although I could easily connect to the DB using codebehind, the server explorer wouldn't connect to the DB.

Luckily after uninstalling 6.2.3 and installing 6.3.0 (from the link above) the MySQL driver was added to VS2010, and I was able to connect to the database and see it in my server explorer.

Answer (score 3):

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=45122

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work by doing the following:

**My Environment:**

- Development Box -- Win7 64bit,
  VS2010 Pro
- Deployment Box -- Win2k8 svr with IIS7
  running ASP.NET .Net 2.0/3.0/3.5 sp which is
  hosted at DiscountAsp.Net (Note:
  DiscountAsp.Net does not provide a
  MySQL DB when running on a Win2k8
  svr, I'm using a MySQL DB that I connect
  to elsewhere on the InterWebs)

**Steps I took:**

1. Installed MySql.Data, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d
2. Ref'd the .Net 2.0 version of the MySQL assembly in my ASP.NET MVC2 Web project set to target .Net 3.5 (the path for the MySQL assemblies I used was C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.3.6\Assemblies\v2.0)
3. I ref'd all 3 of the MySQL assemblies (MySql.Data.dll, MySql.Data.Entity.dll & MySql.Web.dll)
4. I marked each of those assemblies as "Copy Local=True" in my project (a.k.a bin deployment)
5. Added a MySQL DB connection string to my Project (using the MySQL provider)
6. Added an ADO.NET Entity Data Model to my project in VS2010 using the connections string
7. VS2010 took about 30 secs to chew thru my MySQL DB schema but then provided me with a beautiful GUI interface to tweak my MVC Models
8. Used the DB Entities in my MVC controllers
9. Deployed the app to my hosted server at DiscountAsp.Net

It works like a charm :)

Comment: DiscountAsp.Net has since added support for hosting MySQL DBs.  Its available as a fee based add-on (but very reasonably priced).

Answer (score 1):

Erm... through code? Or do you mean the server explorer add-in? Have you tried the latest (albeit GPL-ed) connector version for .NET from Mysql themselves? Again, it's GPL-ed so be aware of the consequences of using that for your own software.

Comment: i'm lazy. i was hoping to do this through the server explorer addin. i have tried the .net connector and visual studio 2010 doesn't seem to pick it up. there is something wrong with the installation methinks.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 is busted for [DDEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Data_Exchange) providers.  They are auto promoting a VS 2008 assembly from 9.0 to 10.0 and it fails.  The failure has to do with the fact that a .NET 2 assembly cannot load a .NET 4 assembly.

This worked in beta 1, so it is something they broke.

I even went back and tried the reference DDEX provider from the SDK.  It won't load in VS 2010 beta 2 either.  That tells me they have something that needs to be fixed.

When is the next beta?