# How to make Mysql .Net connector 6.3.3Beta to work in VS Web Express 2010?

Tags: .net, mysql, visual-studio-2010, database-connection

I have VS Web Express 2010 installed. I have just installed Mysql .Net connector. I have taken version 6.3.3 as it was advised in [this thread][1]. However I have no option to add a connection to Mysql in VS 2010 Express database explorer. Have anybody such a problem?

[1]:      · [How do I connect to MySQL 5.1 in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901049/how-do-i-connect-to-mysql-5-1-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 1):

I also have the problem. Trying to install latest version, 6.4.3 and no luck.

Finally I have found MySQL 5.6 documentation saying:

[Note that MySQL Connector/Net does not currently support Express
 versions of Microsoft products, including Microsoft Visual Web
 Developer.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net.html)

I am going to try MySQL Connector/ODBC instead.