# How do I use MySql with Visual Studio 2010 C++?

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, api

I've been making a game using C# with XNA and using MySql to send data to a server. The other day however, I discovered the Irrlicht engine which is great, but the .NET wrapper is rubbish so I'm moving to C++.

However I can't get my head around the MySql C++ connector at all. I've tried going through the "tutorials" on the official MySql website but had no luck. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and following all of the instructions.

One problem I did have with the instructions was that they mentioned libmysql.dll and libmysql.lib. These simply weren't present in the download. I even tried the windows installer and that only managed to give me the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which document you've read at the official mysql site, but the [MySQL Forge Wiki](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Connector_C++) provides a very good introduction, including installation of the MySQL C++ Connector.

**Update:** [Here](http://www.mologie.de/blog/2010/10/mysql-connector-c-und-visual-studio-2010/) is a link to a blog where the user has uploaded working connectors for C++ and VS2010. It's in german, but that shouldn't be a matter. You can also give [How do I connect to MySQL 5.1 in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901049/how-do-i-connect-to-mysql-5-1-in-visual-studio-2010) a try.

Comment: Reading through it now, looks like I'll have to compile it myself if I want to run it in VS2010? That or just use 2008.

Answer (score 1):

It's working!
Here's what you have to do:

1. Manually install sqlstring.hpp, they
   forgot to put this in the windows
   installer.
2. Install the boost library. (Even
   though you shouldn't have to...)

Comment: Where do i find sqlstring.hpp?