# How do I use SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am trying to create a new report but I am not able to connect to the MySQL database. Any ideas ?

Comment: What happens? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I can't find a place to connect to the MySQL database on the Database expert (wizard)

Comment: And this (although I'm not entirely sure about the Crystal Reports bit): http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=visual+studio+2010+mysql

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I connect to MySQL 5.1 in Visual Studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901049/how-do-i-connect-to-mysql-5-1-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: Pekka, that is not the case. I know how to connect my application to MySQL. My problem is that I am not able to connect to MySQL using the Crystal Reports Database wizard.

Comment: @Guilherme ah, sorry. I'll keep the links in place so others don't make the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Install [ODBC connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/). Create a DSN for the your database. Then you should be able to choose DSN in Crystal Reports' wizard.