# Visual Studio 2010 C++ MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2010

Using Visual Studio's Connect to Database option and the connector from the MySql webpage for .net I have managed to connect to my localhost MySql database and in the server explorer tab in Visual Studio I can see my Tables. Is it possible that in my c++ project to extract that data? If so what is the header that I need to include in order to access the database? Also if it's not possible to connect to my database the way I did it what are my possibilities?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I connect to MySQL 5.1 in Visual Studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901049/how-do-i-connect-to-mysql-5-1-in-visual-studio-2010)