# connecting my sql with visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, mysql-workbench

I want to connect MySql database with visual studio 2010.I have installed sql connector and added connection to the Visual studio  but the problem is that i write the code to open the  database but it doesn't work .here is the code.

```
 public void Connect()
        {

            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;User Id=root;database=students;Password=admin");
                con.Open();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                String exception = ex.ToString();

            }

        }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, what do you mean "it doesn't work?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I connect to MySQL 5.1 in Visual Studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901049/how-do-i-connect-to-mysql-5-1-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SqlConnection` is for SQL Server, not MySQL.

You need to install a MySQL client from NuGet.

Comment: Why installing a 3d party tool? You can get all you need directly from MySQL. Start with Connector .NET.

Comment: @MikeLischke: Who said anything about 3rd-party tools? http://nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/

Answer (score 0):

Hey use oledb connection instead of sqlconnection.

Otherwise MySql client dll available. Download and use it.